# How to compare against the prefix of a word

Tags: python, if-statement

Let me explain with a quick bit of code.

Code:

```
choice = raw_input("Do you like pineapple? Y/N: ")
if choice == "y".lower() or choice == "ye".lower() or choice == "yes".lower():
    print("Sammmmeee")
else:
    print("Nani! You criminal!")
```

How could I make it so instead of doing:

```
if choice == "y".lower() or choice == "ye".lower() or choice == "yes".lower():
```

it automatically accepts, `"y"`, `"ye"` or `"yes"` without needing to do `or` so much?

Comment: I've updated your title and removed the self-deprecating intro. I had a pretty good idea what the question was going to be even before that, so don't sell yourself short. Also good job using `or` correctly to begin with. Judging by a lot of the questions here, it's not intuitively easy.

Comment: Thank you for making the title more understandable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to achieve this:

```
if 'yes'.startswith(choice.lower().strip()):
   print('You said "yes"!')
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't be applying `lower` to the right hand side, which is a constant and already lowercase. You should be applying it to the variable input:

```
choice = raw_input(...).lower()
```

There are a number of ways to check for the match you are looking for. The easiest is to use `startswith`:

```
if 'yes'.startswith(choice):
```

Another way would be to explicitly check for containment in a set or tuple:

```
if choice in ('y', 'ye', 'yes'):
```

This is only necessary for cases that don't fit into a simple method check, like if you wanted to add `ok` to the list of options.

If you wanted to have multiple function checks, you could use `any` with a generator expression:

```
if any(f(x) for f in ('yes'.startswith, 'ok'.startswith)):
```

All of the tests here are properly short circuiting, just like your original expression.

Answer (score 1):

This will case-insensitively match exactly `'y'`, `'ye'`, and `'yes'`:

```
choice = raw_input("Do you like pineapple? Y/N: ")
if choice.lower() == 'yes'[:len(choice)]:
    print("Sammmmeee")
else:
    print("Nani! You criminal!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pick the first character of the input to compare with 'y'. Also note that you need to make the input lowercase. So the code becomes:

```
choice = raw_input("Do you like pineapple? Y/N: ")[0]
if choice.lower() == "y":
    print("Sammmmeee")
else:
    print("Nani! You criminal!")
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way the OP requests it: for example, your code would accept 'yerk!' as a yes, which it shouldn't.